# Hazelcast - Error in reading cache with 2 million objects with apprx 500 requests/second read

Tags: hazelcast

We have apprx 2 million distributed data objects(not replicated) in cache of 10 nodes cluster (apprx 500 MB data). Backup count is one. We are seeing given below errors/warnings. 
Do you guys know when I can see these errors? I have sanitize some logs to not share something sensitive. Majority of time we do cache read(around 400 request/second), and whole cache gets reinitialized every 2 hours.

I know that we can do replicated cache to improve performance, but wondering what's wrong going on here. When I run with smaller cluster(e.g. 5 nodes) then everything works fine.

- Hazelcast version 3.6.3
- Server size 8 core, 16 GB
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- IO Input thread count size is 30
- IO Output thread count size is 50

> 2017-06-24 23:46:22.679 ERROR (hz._hzInstance_1_My-App.partition-operation.thread-5) [c.h.m.i.o.GetOperation] - [192.168.111.11]:5701 [My-App] [3.6.3] Cannot send response: HeapData{type=-2, hashCode=113248027, partitionHash=113248027, totalSize=722, dataSize=714, heapCost=742} to Address[192.168.111.13]:5701. Op: com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation{identityHash=1124265765, serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', partitionId=189, replicaIndex=0, callId=3490089, invocationTime=1498362385498 (Sat Jun 24 23:46:25 EDT 2017), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=8000, name=HKF/my-cache-id-3, name=HKF/my-cache-id-3}
>   com.hazelcast.spi.exception.ResponseNotSentException: Cannot send response: HeapData{type=-2, hashCode=113248027, partitionHash=113248027, totalSize=722, dataSize=714, heapCost=742} to Address[192.168.111.13]:5701. Op: com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation{identityHash=1124265765, serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', partitionId=189, replicaIndex=0, callId=3490089, invocationTime=1498362385498 (Sat Jun 24 23:46:25 EDT 2017), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=8000, name=HKF/my-cache-id-3, name=HKF/my-cache-id-3}
>   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.RemoteInvocationResponseHandler.sendResponse(RemoteInvocationResponseHandler.java:54)
>   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.sendResponse(OperationRunnerImpl.java:278)
>   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.handleResponse(OperationRunnerImpl.java:251)
>   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:173)
>   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:393)
>   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.processPacket(OperationThread.java:184)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have such huge number of input and output threads (30/50). In most cases the default of 3+3 is more than sufficient. If you don't have 50+ connections; all these threads will be idle. Even with 50+ connections, you will not get good performance with so many IO threads.

The error you are seeing seems to indicate a networking issue: response can't be send. The big question is why this is happening.

Can you enable diagnostics:

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Management/Diagnostics/Enabling_Diagnostics_Logging.html

And send the log files to peter at hazelcast dot com So I can have a look at it.

Comment: We set the "read IO" threads count to 50 thinking that if current node is reading 50 data objects from remote node at a given moment, it will need 50 threads. Just so you know, read from cache synchronously. Let me know if that's not needed. There are cases when we can do upto 2000 reads/seconds.

Comment: For diagnostic, I will have to rerun the load tests. I will get back to you in couple of days.

Comment: 1 connection per node and 1 connection is handled by 2 threads; one for input and one for output. On a 4 node cluster, the maximum of used IO threads is the default of 3+3 since each member will have 3 connections to each other member.

Also if there are more connections than IO threads, the IO threads can rely on pipelining; so they read or write a much bigger chunk of data and thereby reducing overhead.

So reset the number of IO threads to default.

Comment: What is the size of the keys/values? So how many do you have and what is roughly their size? Are we talking about a few kb, or about a lot bigger values. To give you some impression based on a test for a customer; on our lab with 10 boxes and 10KB values, 4 members, 60 clients (on 6 machines) and 40 threads per client, we do 1.25M gets per second (with TLS enabled!)

Comment: Definitely less than 10 KB. We have apprx 2 millions objects and memory taken by these objects is around 500-600 MB. I thought that if we are reading from cache Synchronously then number of IO Read threads count should be higher. One thing I forgot to highlight is, that we start Hazelcast and Vertx App in same JVM process, and Vertx App act as a client to read data from Hazelcast cache while service HTTP request. If we are using a cluster of 10-15 nodes(which means 10-15 clients)? Sorry if I am asking too many question, since I don't know internal working of Hazelcast.

Comment: Just so you know, Vertx (vertx.io) starts Hazelcast internally and uses it for discovery of other nodes when started in clustered mode. Our app is written on top of Vertx, and we uses same Hazelcast instance that was started by Vertx. We don't use any wrapper from Vertx, and directly read/write into Hazelcast IMaps.